# Fabric Js - Create rectangle around freehand drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a application in which users can create the following and write some comments for each Square they create. We are using FabricJs for create the following.
1) Square
2) Free hand tool

Once the user creates a Square, we are displaying a input control exactly at the bottom-right corner of the Square.

Now, the problem is where should I display the "Input" controls for for "Free hand tool"? One idea is to create another Square around the Free hand tool. Is there a way to get the height and width of the Freehand shape area?

Please help.

I am using Fabric Js for drawing the shapes.

Thanks in Advance.
Prawin

Comment: Anything like that?  http://jsfiddle.net/ryv1ftt8/ - press "Enter drawing mode"

Comment: Yup. it was something similar. However, the sample that you have shown displays the free hand drawing only on "Mouseup" event.

Comment: We have got an alternate by using the getBoundingRect

Comment: We have got an alternate by using the getBoundingRect. Basically, this function provides you the rectangle (with controls to resize the rect) and we are displaying the input control on the right bottom corner of the rectangle object whose co-ordinates are returned by the getBoundingRect() function.. Thank you!!